# What is the difference between IBM874 and MS874?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, collation, iso-8859-1, thai

I am trying to add Thai Collation support in my driver and to do so, I need to use the appropriate character encoding. So after some research, I am left with the two options :

Code page 874, which is also known as CP874 and **IBM874** 
 and 
Code page 1162, which is also known as windows-874, CP1162, IBM1162, **MS874**, x-windows-874, and x-IBM874

They both seem to belong to the family [ISO/IEC 8859-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-11) and only differ from it by a couple of (8 to 9) symbols, which is nearly identical to the Thai Standard [TIS-620](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_Industrial_Standard_620-2533)

My question is, which among the two (IBM874 and MS874), would be the best choice to provide support for Thai Collation.

I tried both one after the other and both seem to do the job. I cannot seem to find much information about the two on google.

Can someone please help me understand which among the two is a more appropriate or comprehensive choice ?

P.S: I found an [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) which mentions about the two and the only notable difference I see is that :

MS874 is described as "Windows Thai" and is categorized under "Extended Encoding Set" - International Version
whereas 
IBM874 as described as "IBM Thai" and falls under "Basic Encoding Set" - European Version

The 'International Version' seems to support all encodings listed on the Oracle page. So I am guessing that is the more extensive or appropriate choice and so I am planning to go ahead with MS874. Am i missing something?

Comment: If you should support one, you need to know what the user of your driver uses. The better methods: allows all encoding, and possibly let's OS (or libraries) to do the collation. Consider to use Unicode (which it is a superset of most other encodings), but CP874 is a superset of IBM874, so by supporting CP, you support IBM. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-11

Comment: Giacomo Catenazzi, but that still does not help me understand if I should suppport IBM or MS version of the encoding.

As my question suggests, I am trying to understand which option is more comprehensive and from what I have found so far (Oracle doc link above), MS874 seems like the best way to go. But I wanted to get a second opinion on that.

Thanks for your help on this so far!